# Cut ':' && " " from a String with a tokenizer

Tags: java, eclipse

right now I am a little bit confused. I want to manipulate this string with a tokenizer:

```
Bob:23456:12345 Carl:09876:54321
```

However, I use a Tokenizer, but when I try:

> ```
>       String signature1 = tok.nextToken(":");             
>       tok.nextToken(" ")
> ```

I get:

> 12345 Carl

However I want to have the first int and the second int into a var.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different patterns, maybe you should handle both separated.

Fist you should split the space separated values. Only use the string `split(" ")`. That will return a `String[]`.

Then for each `String` use tokenizer.

I believe will works.

Code:

```
String input = "Bob:23456:12345 Carl:09876:54321";
String[] words = input.split(" ")

for (String word : words) {
  String[] token = each.split(":");

  String name = token[0];
  int value0 = Integer.parseInt(token[1]);
  int value1 = Integer.parseInt(token[2]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should do:

```
String input = "Bob:23456:12345 Carl:09876:54321";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, ": ");

while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String name = st.nextToken();
    String val1 = st.nextToken();
    String val2 = st.nextToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have multiple patterns, you cannot handle them with only one tokenizer.

You need to first split it based on `whitespace`, then split based on the `colon`.

Something like this should help:

```
String[] s = "Bob:23456:12345 Carl:09876:54321".split(" ");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s ));

String[] so = s[0].split(":", 2);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(so));
```

And you'd get this:

```
[Bob:23456:12345, Carl:09876:54321]
[Bob, 23456:12345]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use tokeniser then I tink you need to use it twice

```
String str = "Bob:23456:12345 Carl:09876:54321";
StringTokenizer spaceTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
while (spaceTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    StringTokenizer colonTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(spaceTokenizer.nextToken(), ":");
    colonTokenizer.nextToken();//to igore Bob and Carl
    while (colonTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
         System.out.println(colonTokenizer.nextToken());
    }
}
```

outputs

```
23456 
12345
09876
54321
```

Personally though I would not use tokenizer here and use Claudio's answer which splits the strings.